# Mixing two linq statement into one?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have 2 linq statements, both of them are fully working. I am wondering if it is possible to mix them into one and get proper list after one linq.

```
var result = list3.Where(Srodek => list4.Any(x => x == Srodek.Srodek.category1) &&
                                  (Srodek.Srodek.Source.Device == _text || Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device == _text))
                  .ToList();
var list666 = list3.Select(obj => new { obj, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
                   .Where(x => x.dt >= czas11 && x.dt <= czas22)
                   .Select(x => x.obj).ToList();
```

Comment: How do these lists interact? How is the resulting list built?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You're not referencing `result` from the `list666` expression, so how would you "combine" these?

Comment: What would "proper list" be? As far as I can see, result is not referenced in the second statement, so how do you expect to combine them?

Comment: I know I am not referencing result from list666, I am working on list3, which is my main list. These statements are called from different methods, but I was wandering if I can do it all in one.

Comment: What would you expect as a final output? It looks like you have two unrelated things here.

Comment: Even if you could obtain 2 Collections, one with the results of the first statement and the second with the results of the other, it would make your code way harder to understand for no real reason...

Comment: I would like to get one list which will be result from both linq statment performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One list:

```
var result = list3.Where(obj => {
                              var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                              return (list4.Any(x => x == obj.Srodek.category1) &&
                              (obj.Srodek.Source.Device == _text || obj.Srodek.ID.Device == _text)) ||
                              (dt >= czas11 && dt <= czas22);})       
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Not working :( obj doesn't exist and nere `||` cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'lambda expression'.

Comment: @user2592968 yes, the `third )` (after `==_text))`) is redundant, updated.

Comment: But it is stil showing only results from this statement `(dt >= czas11 && dt <= czas22)`

Comment: @user2592968 it can't because I use the `||` to separate 2 conditions. You should copy the code (don't modify it yourself).

Comment: Ok, now it is working. I needed AND not OR in there in my case. Thank you King King, as always you are providing best answers :D

Answer (score 4):

LINQ methods return [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), and can operate on [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx).

You can write

```
sequence.Where(...).Select(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you cant just mix them? list.where(.........).select(.......).toList();

```
var result = list3.Where(Srodek => list4.Any(x => x == Srodek.Srodek.category1) &&
                         (Srodek.Srodek.Source.Device == _text || Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device== _text))
                   .Select(obj => new { obj, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
                  .Where(x => x.dt >= czas11 && x.dt <= czas22)
                  .Select(x => x.obj)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join both linq queries using `Union`.

```
list3.Where(Srodek => list4.Any(x => x == Srodek.Srodek.category1) &&
                              (Srodek.Srodek.Source.Device == _text || Srodek.Srodek.ID.Device == _text))
               .Union(list3.Select(obj => new { obj, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
               .Where(x => x.dt >= czas11 && x.dt <= czas22)
               .Select(x => x.obj));
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it is only showing results from this part `list3.Select(obj => new { obj, dt = DateTime.ParseExact(obj.LeftColumn, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
               .Where(x => x.dt >= czas11 && x.dt <= czas22)
               .Select(x => x.obj));`